# Symplectic group of elementary abelian group.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

It is well known that if 
$$A=C_p\times C_p,$$
then 
$$SP(A)=SL_2(p).$$
That is, the symplectic group of $A$ is equal to the special linear group.
I am looking for a generalizeation for any elementary abelian group $G$.
In particular, what is the symplectic group of
$$G=C_p^{2m}.$$
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group

Comment: An accessible introduction to finite symplectic groups is chapter 8 of Donald E. Taylor's "The Geometry of the Classical Groups".

Comment: מה קורה אופיר - מה זה $SP(A)$? בברכה מארץ הקוידש